# VBA Excel: Paste into Matching Row between Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to develop code to do the following:

```
1)Copy cells K4: M4 in Workbook 1, Sheet 1 <- I can do this step;

2)Find a cell in Workbook2, Sheet1, column C that matches cell B4 in
Workbook1, Sheet1;

3)Paste the copied values in columns P:R of the matching row in
Workbook 2, Sheet 1 as determined in Step 2.
```

My apologies in advance for being unable to advance my own work beyond step 1.  I am, as I said, completely new to this and have scoured the web for an answer/learnings up until this point, without turning up a solution.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you can do this with worksheet formulas instead of VBA. Is that some thing you would consider?

Comment: I am hoping to automate and streamline the work as much as possible; so ideally, I would prefer to go the Visual Basic route.

Comment: I agree with @SomeSillyName. Have you used `Vlookup` before?

Comment: Hi Brad. I'm very familiar and comfortable with Vlookup.  In this case, I'm hoping automate the work process however, and vlookup does not serve my needs.  Thank you for the suggestion however.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and it worked. Does this help you get started?

```
Sub CopyToMatchedRow()
    Dim copyRng As Range, matchVal As Variant, matchRng As Range, matchRow As Integer

    Set copyRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K4:M4")
    Set matchRng = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C:C")
    matchVal = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4")
    matchRow = matchRng.Find(What:=matchVal, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    copyRng.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("P" & matchRow & ":R" & matchRow)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Remnant! I can't quite get it to work, however. I've modified it to go between Workbooks, but get a run-time eror '13' type mismatch message. Any ideas? I changed the following lines: Set copyRng = Workbooks("Workbook1").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K4:M4") Set matchRng = Workbooks("Workbook2").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C") matchVal = Workbooks("Worbook1").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4") copyRng.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Workbook2").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("P" & matchRow & ":R" & matchRow) End Sub

Comment: I also just tried it between sheets in the same workbook, exactly as shared, and I receive the same error message :(  Debug is highlighting the matchRow command.

Comment: If 1matchRow` is giving an error it may be because it cannot find a match. Does your `matchVal` exist in the `matchRng`?

Comment: Yes, my cell B4 in Sheet1 matches exactly a cell in column C in Sheet2.  I'm genuinely puzzled.

Comment: Have you tested it manually by using the `Match()` function in the spreadsheet? Might be worth checking that first?

Comment: The Match() function in the spreadsheet does indeed return the proper position. Strange.